How to get notified only when a text box is edited by the user in C++ Win 32 API?
I am building a C++ app with Win32 api interface
I have a text box that changes programmatically and user can also set the value in text box. I want to get a notification in WM_COMMAND only when it is changed by the user.
I tried EN_CHANGE, but its hit every time when the textbox is changed.
Is there a way to solve this?
if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE) 
    {
            height = abc.SetHeight(hwnd, EDIT_10); // Get the values from height box only when user changes it
            abc.SetDefaultHeight(height);
            return TRUE;
    }


Maybe via WM_KEYDOWN ?

That would need me to add the logic to add up the digits ? Is there no simpler way of doing this

I am not sure. Just thought it might be a direction. Maybe you can listen to WM_KEYDOWN just to be aware that some change happened, then forward it to the default event handler (for standard handling of the keyboard events), and check the content of the edit box via the usual API.

Actually your code should know when and how you change the textbox content programmatically. So your code logic could suspend eventhandling for EN_CHANGE before you change programmatically (e.g. via a state indicator variable) and after you've seen the modification by code just resume to handling potential user action.

Yeah, I have added a bool to solve this; Thanks alot

Found a way:  Added a  BOOL which is set to false just before SetDlgItemText() and set back to TRUE at the end of WIN_WRITE.
And add if (flag) inside EN_CHANGE to do what I want when user edits the textbox. Works fine

This is the standard solution. Because you do want to react to programmatic changes from other apps (such as assistive technology tools).

Excellent. You can accept your own answer.
